# Asp.Net Core Identity with multiple SAML IDPs using ITFoxTec.Identity.Saml2

Tags: itfoxtec-identity-saml2

Are there any examples of using itfoxtec-identity-saml2 with asp.net core Identity.
Specifically, I have many SAML Idps (https://stubidp.sustainsys.com, Okta, Auth0, Salesforce, etc) and I want to add them using AuthenticationBuilder.

```cs
 public static class Saml2Extensions
    {
        public static AuthenticationBuilder AddSaml(this AuthenticationBuilder builder, string authenticationScheme, string displayName, Action<Saml2Options> configureOptions)
        {
         ...
        }
    }
```

A good example would have a mix in of Google, Azure both using OIDC, and a few SAML ones.
[image: Multiple IdP login Page]

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid that I do not have sutch an example. I always put a proxy / broker IdP in between, in my case I use [FoxIDs](https://foxids.com). That way the application only need to know about one IdP and would then ask the broker IdP to handle the up-stream IdP authentication.

Comment: FoxId question:
We are running our own accounts.mycorp.com server and having issues bringing in multiple SAML idps.  Can I use FoxId as a way to front SAML idps and expose them to me as OIDC?  i.e. outsource my SAML problem, where something like the demo sustainsys idp which is SAML, is now OpenID connect.

Comment: Yes you can let FoxIDs handle the multible SAML 2.0 IdP's, configured in FoxIDs as up-parties. And only have one OpenID Connection from your application to FoxIDs, configured in FoxIDs a down-party. Your application can select the up-party doing the login request or let the user select the up-party.